# Obtener parametros de URL y pasarlos a input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

***Quiero obtener los parametros de la url al cargar la pagina en un input***

*he realizado 2 codigos diferentes y ningun logra obtener los parametros de la URL*

**ejemplo de url https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01o_e2LQtu- **

*En este primer codigo me arroja el error [object HTMLInputElement]*

```
   <input type="text" id="nomenclatura" name="nomenclatura" class="form-control" />


  <script>

      window.onload;

      const url = window.location.search;
      const urlParametro = new URLSearchParams(url);
      const parametro = urlParametro.get("parametro");
      const nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
      nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + nomenclatura;



      alert(nomenclatura);




  </script>
```

*En este segundo codigo no logro tomar los valores y ponerlos en el inpu*

```
   <input type="text" id="nomenclatura" name="nomenclatura" class="form-control" />

  <script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
const valores = window.location.search;

//Mostramos los valores en consola:
console.log(valores);

//Creamos la instancia
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(valores);

//Accedemos a los valores
var producto = urlParams.get('nomenclatura');

// Seleccionamos y agregamos val al input

var nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
      nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + nomenclatura;

});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

En ambos ejemplos que colocaste:

```
  window.onload;

  const url = window.location.search;
  const urlParametro = new URLSearchParams(url);
  const parametro = urlParametro.get("parametro");
  const nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
  nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + nomenclatura;
```

estás llenando el input "nomenclatura" con el valor equivocado, estás poniendo:

```
  nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + nomenclatura;
```

en vez de

```
  nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + parametro;
```

(basado en el primer ejemplo),

el código quedaría así:

```
  <input type="text" id="nomenclatura" name="nomenclatura" class="form-control" />


  <script>
  window.onload;

  const url = window.location.search;
  const urlParametro = new URLSearchParams(url);
  const parametro = urlParametro.get("editor_console");
  
  
  const nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
  nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + parametro;
  </script>
```

Podrías ver el resultado que me dio, aquí: **https://jsfiddle.net/zjq73txb/7/**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que mandas llamar un parametro que no existe en la URL que pones de ejemplo, estás llamando el parámetro **"parametro"**: `const parametro = urlParametro.get("parametro");`, cuando el único parámetro es el **sxsrf**.

Y en esta línea, estas queriendo imprimir un objeto dentro de la propiedad `value` del objeto **nomenclatura:** `nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + nomenclatura;`, lo cual no es posible y te marcará error en `consola`.

Por lo tanto, el código ya corregido sería este:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
var parametro = params.get('sxsrf');

var nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + parametro;
alert(parametro);
```

Comment: var parametro = params.get('sxsrf'); en realidad es tomar los parametros de distintas url pero ambos codigos me arroja NULL

Comment: Prueba cambiando las constantes por variables.

Answer (score 0):

*Ambos script me arrojan null y [object HTMLInputElement]*

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
var parametro = params.get('parametro');

var nomenclatura = document.getElementById("nomenclatura");
nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + parametro;

alert(parametro);

  nomenclatura.value = "nomenclatura: " + parametro;

alert(nomenclatura);
```

Comment: De preferencia actualiza tu pregunta con esta información, ya que esto no es una respuesta... Añade la URL con la que realizaste esta prueba... y ` [object HTMLInputElement]` quiere decir que estás mandando a imprimir un objeto de tipo `input`, no le veo la necesidad de hacer eso.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        if(window.location.hash) {          
          var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
          $("#folio").append(""+hash+"");
      } else {
          $("#folio").append("<p> No hay ningun hash en la URL </p>");
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Gracias por el aporte, pero deberias leerte [answer] para aprender a realizar buenas respuestas.  Solo poniendo el código sin explicar cómo eso resuelve la pregunta no ayuda a comprender tu respuesta. Léete tambien en [tour] para saber cómo funciona este sitio. Gracias.