# Pasar un parámetro de una pagina a otra mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Hola como podría pasar una id de un parámetro, y cuando se cargue la otra página recoja esa id?
Tengo el código en la plantillas tal que así

```html
<div class="text-center mt-5 mb-3">
                        <a href="/general/recibo/add" onclick="pagar_recibo({{ alumno.pk }})" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Pagar
                        </a>
                        <a href="{{ list_url }}" class="btn btn-danger ">
                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i> Volver
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

La función de esa plantilla está en un js llamado multiple.js

```html
export var alumn_id

export async function pagar_recibo(id) {
    $.ajax ({
        delay: 250,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/general/recibo/add',
        data:  {
            'id': id,
            'action': 'add_alumnos',
        },
    });
    alumn_id = id;
};

window.pagar_recibo = pagar_recibo;
```

Luego en el otro js que se llama form, tengo lo siguiente

```html
import { alumn_id} from '../../alumno/js/multiple.js';
$ ( function () {

    console.log(alumn_id);
```

Y luego sigue mas código, pero el id pasado es indefinido
Como consigo pasarle ese valor?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrias pasarlo por la URL o el local storage, aca te dejo un par de ejemplos, http://mialtoweb.es/pasar-variables-por-la-url-en-javascript/ https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427416/obtener-parametros-de-url-y-pasarlos-a-input y para el local storage estos te pueden servir https://victorroblesweb.es/2017/10/29/como-usar-localstorage-javascript/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb8O0qRqiSk

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, el segundo enlace me viene perfecto, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías pasarlo como parametro en la URL

Página desde donde lo mandas, esta parte puede ser un evento de JS de donde obtienes lo que mandaras y la acción para redireccionar:

```
document.location.href = `paginaADondeSeManda.php?tuParametro=${encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(LoQueMandas))}`;
```

Página que lo recibe con PHP:

```
<?php
    $parametroRecibido = $_GET['tuParametro'];
?>
```